# CSS Hover: How to set up different content at hover for a small box with html content

Tags: html, css

Here's what I need to achieve. I have a small box (button) with html content including an icon font and text.

```
<a class="box-locked"><span class="heading-icon-non-members"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>Getting Started</a>
```

Note that the icon class is "fa fa-home" which display a home shape icon (using font awesome) with the text bellow 'Getting Started'.

Here's the CSS for the small box:

```
.box-locked {
display: inline-block;
height: 170px;
width: 155px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
text-align: center;
padding:10px;
padding-top:1rem;
padding-bottom:1rem;
padding-right:2.5rem;
padding-left:2.5rem;
font-size: 18px;
font-size: 1.2857143rem;
font-weight:700;
color:#757575;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-bottom: 2rem;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-right: 1.5rem;
vertical-align:top;
line-height:1.1;}

.heading-icon-non-members {
font-size: 55px;
font-size: 4rem;
color:#757575;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
text-align:center;
}
```

You can see the visual result here: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0bc2139r90

The goal is to display on hover another type of content. It should display a 'lock icon' with text bellow 'members only'.

I would rather prefer to do it without using a background-image because the site should be fully responsive and the box will have a full width on small screens.

Comment: looks like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp) could solve your issue.

Comment: you can easily use both of them and hide one or the other if hovered ...

Comment: @Damon: How can this solve the issue? Can you show how to apply the css in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could either do it with the `content` property, or it might just be easier (and support older browsers) to do it with Javascript.

Comment: Have no experience with Javascript. If you have any recommendation on how to do it with Java?

Comment: Well I definitely wouldn't even try it with Java as that is a completely different language ;)

If you're completely new to Javascript, check out jQuery. It's very simple to get to grips with without having to worry about browser inconsistencies, and there are loads of tutorials for it.

Comment: I believe you, when I have time, I'll learn Java, but for now it's not the solution for me, thanks.